# Equation* with split same as align*

Tags: equations, align

If I want to have a single multiline equation with alignment (but no labelling), is it the same to use:

Equation* with split

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

Align*

```
\begin{align*}
\end{align*}
```

I am aware that without the star*, the difference is that align labels every single line whilst equation with split labels the entire equation once. However, if I don't want labels, are both equivalent (spacing wise, etc.)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the spacing may be different, and with `align*` you have the possibility of page breaks within the alignment.

Comment: Hence, is it correct to say that equation* with split is recommended if one intends to type a single equation? Is there a shorter version that is equivalent to it (to be easier to type)?

Comment: @yoyostein I'd possibly use `aligned` rather than `split` but the typing is the same either way. In deciding whether to use `align*` instead I think the way to think of it is _if_ you changed your mind and wanted a number would you want one centred number (use `equation*` and aligned or split)  or would you number most lines (use `align*`)